# How to pass JSON Array inside JSON object to jQuery autocomplete

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete to receive specific data via Ajax call. The data I receive from Ajax call is a JSON object which contain a JSON array in it. I need to show each result of this json array into autocomplete search results.The format would be something like this :

```
{
    "returnCode":"success",
    "status":"success", 
    "searchResults" :[{"val":"123"},{"val":"456"},{"val":"789"}]
   }
```

Now I need to show 123 456 and 789 in autocomplete dropdown. Tried some code in formatItem and formatResult, but doesn't seem to serve the purpose.

```
formatItem: function(row,i,max) {
var returnObject = eval("(" + row + ")");
var searchResults = returnObject.searchResults;
if(searchResults.length>0){
    for(i=1; i<searchResults.length; i++){
        // What to do here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var cache = {};
elem.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var term = request.term;
      if (!!cache[term]) {
        response(cache[term][0]);
        return
      };
      cache[term] = [];
      $.getJSON("/path/to/json/")
      .then(function success(data) {
          var res = $.map(data.searchResults, function(val) {
            return val.val
          });          
          cache[term].push(res);
          response(res)
        }, function error(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(textStatus, errorThrown) // log `$.ajax` errors
      })
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/wr1wg5df/

Comment: I have tried using 'source' for making my ajax call. Although somehow it doesn't work. The ajax call is never made.

Comment: Tried pattern at post ? Can include `$.ajax()` , `.autocomplete()` at original post ? What is logged at `console` ?

Comment: nothing. Seems like it doesn't support the 'source' thing at all

Comment: Can  include `$.ajax()` , `.autocomplete()` `js` at original post ?, create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: So basically when I call the java method giving url param in autocomplete it works - $(modal).find(".seach").autocomplete("searchListItems.do",{

Comment: But when I try to do the same using source it doesn't - $(modal).find(".seach").autocomplete({ source: function(request, response) {
          $.getJSON("searchListItems.do", {

Comment: Is response received utilizing url param ? If possible, can include `js` at original post ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72553/discussion-between-gaurav-varma-and-guest271314).